# How to exclude Office 2013 support from Excel AddIn manifest

Tags: office-js, excel-addins, office-store

I am using latest office API 2016+ API and trying to exclude Office 2013 support from manifest.

There are quite a few articles around, but can't find a sample XML with valid manifest.

Will appreciate a sample manifest file where minimum "requirements" excludes office 2013 (Excel 2013).

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The requirement set says which minimum version(s) are supported (not what you want to exclude). Simple solution to exclude 2013 is to add 1.1 support in the manifest:

```
<Requirements>
   <Sets DefaultMinVersion="1.1">
      <Set Name="ExcelApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>
   </Sets>
</Requirements>
```

Comment: Hi. Do you know how to exclude Office 2013 from PowerPoint add-in? `office-addin-validator` throws an error on `<Set Name="PowerPointApi" MinVersion="1.1"/>`